# Nested column header error in javafx for java 8 b-124

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, tablecolumn

in javaFX, I have added dianamically column in table view as one parent column and two are child columns of it. then i got specific output in java 8 b-109 but when i run same code in java 8 b-124 then i got following error. so, please help me.

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.NestedTableColumnHeader.dispose(NestedTableColumnHeader.java:323)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.NestedTableColumnHeader.updateTableColumnHeaders(NestedTableColumnHeader.java:265)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.NestedTableColumnHeader.checkState(NestedTableColumnHeader.java:519)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.NestedTableColumnHeader.computePrefHeight(NestedTableColumnHeader.java:401)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.prefHeight(Parent.java:918)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.prefHeight(Region.java:1438)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableHeaderRow.computePrefHeight(TableHeaderRow.java:344)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableHeaderRow.computeMinHeight(TableHeaderRow.java:339)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.minHeight(Parent.java:946)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.minHeight(Region.java:1404)
    at javafx.scene.control.SkinBase.computeMinHeight(SkinBase.java:254)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.computeMinHeight(Control.java:485)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.minHeight(Parent.java:946)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.minHeight(Region.java:1404)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.computeChildMinAreaHeight(Region.java:1700)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.getMaxAreaHeight(Region.java:1981)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.computeMaxMinAreaHeight(Region.java:1850)
    at javafx.scene.layout.HBox.computeMinHeight(HBox.java:419)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.minHeight(Parent.java:946)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.minHeight(Region.java:1404)
    at javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane.computeHeight(AnchorPane.java:297)
    at javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane.computeMinHeight(AnchorPane.java:246)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.minHeight(Parent.java:946)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.minHeight(Region.java:1404)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.computeChildMinAreaHeight(Region.java:1700)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.getMaxAreaHeight(Region.java:1981)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.computeMaxMinAreaHeight(Region.java:1850)
    at javafx.scene.layout.HBox.computeMinHeight(HBox.java:419)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.minHeight(Parent.java:946)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.minHeight(Region.java:1404)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.computeChildMinAreaHeight(Region.java:1700)
    at javafx.scene.layout.VBox.getAreaHeights(VBox.java:440)
    at javafx.scene.layout.VBox.computeContentHeight(VBox.java:522)
    at javafx.scene.layout.VBox.computeMinHeight(VBox.java:400)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.minHeight(Parent.java:946)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.minHeight(Region.java:1404)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.computeChildMinAreaHeight(Region.java:1700)
    at javafx.scene.layout.VBox.getAreaHeights(VBox.java:440)
    at javafx.scene.layout.VBox.computeContentHeight(VBox.java:522)
    at javafx.scene.layout.VBox.computeMinHeight(VBox.java:400)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.minHeight(Parent.java:946)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.minHeight(Region.java:1404)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.computeChildPrefAreaHeight(Region.java:1765)
    at javafx.scene.layout.VBox.getAreaHeights(VBox.java:446)
    at javafx.scene.layout.VBox.computeContentHeight(VBox.java:522)
    at javafx.scene.layout.VBox.computePrefHeight(VBox.java:421)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.prefHeight(Parent.java:918)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.prefHeight(Region.java:1438)
    at javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane.computeHeight(AnchorPane.java:297)
    at javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane.computePrefHeight(AnchorPane.java:254)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.prefHeight(Parent.java:918)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.prefHeight(Region.java:1438)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.minHeight(Region.java:1406)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ScrollPaneSkin.computeScrollNodeSize(ScrollPaneSkin.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ScrollPaneSkin.layoutChildren(ScrollPaneSkin.java:791)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.layoutChildren(Control.java:574)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1076)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1082)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1082)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1082)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1082)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1082)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1082)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1082)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1082)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1082)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1082)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Scene.java:576)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2386)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:322)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:320)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:320)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:349)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:479)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:460)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit$13.run(QuantumToolkit.java:327)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(WinApplication.java:39)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(WinApplication.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: It's probably worth trying on the latest build (b128) - I remember seeing some bug fixes around nested headers a few weeks ago.

Comment: Same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21697949/how-to-resolve-nested-column-in-tableview-afetr-update-version-of-java-124-in-ja/22078957#22078957

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue may be is due to the newer relies, i have tried it with the b129, but getting same error..... The error does not comes to fresh(newly created) table.

Finally I got the temp solution, I use to create new table every time I want to change (any change like adding new column, removing column, swapping columns) the table columns.

Comment: Thanks to give me solution.